# too much .css files are generated in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, vercel

I'm using nextjs. I'm using sass For style layout. All styles are named with *.module.scss, and they are placed in the components folder and its subfolders and not in the styles folder mentioned by the nextjs document. I don't know how to config this situation in next.config.js. Content of my next.config.js is now:

```js
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const nextTranslate = require("next-translate");
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");
const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

// next.js configuration
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    domains: ['ibexcdn.com'],
  },
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [
      nextTranslate,
      {
        webpack: (config, { isServer, webpack }) => {
          return config;
        },
      },
    ],
    withBundleAnalyzer,

    [
      withPWA,
      {
        pwa: {
          disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
          dest: 'public',
          runtimeCaching: [
            {
              urlPattern: /.(?:eot|otf|ttc|ttf|woff|woff2|font.css)$/i,
              handler: 'NetworkFirst',
              options: {
                cacheName: 'static-font-assets',
                expiration: {
                  maxEntries: 4,
                  maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 7 days
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },

      },
    ],
  ],
  nextConfig,
);
```

Comment: What is your question? Multiple CSS files are generated due to code splitting. If you want to opt out of this behavior, you'll need to configure webpack loaders. Refer: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config

Comment: @brc-dd I think the optimal solution is that just one webpack file should be generated but now too many .js and .css files are generated.